# Google does not see the backlinks on the web pages of the domains it indexes

Tags: google-search-console, google-index, backlinks

I have 1 main domain and a web page connected to it. I have 5 different domains and web pages.

I have different content on the same topic in my 5 different domains. In these other 5 different domains, I give backlinks as "We provide these services, click this button, review it on our home page". each domain/website consists of a single page.

I added them all on the Google search console, I see that they are indexed. But when I enter the "links" in my main domain, I see that 2 of my domains have backlinks. In fact, they are all indexed, google bots visit them all, read them all..

The result is the same for about 5 weeks. I gave dofollow backlink. they are all mobile friendly, have sitemaps, 404 pages and robots.txt information. They get an average SEO score of over 70%.

Why can't my other domains show up as "links" in my main domain?
.. does anyone have an idea?

Comment: Maybe the Googlebot thinks you are trying to create artificial back-links.

Comment: "average SEO score of over 70%" -- From what tool?